# jQuery hash changed wildcard

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I'm currently building a dynamic website based on jQuery en hashChanged.
Currently I use this code on document.ready:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    switch(location.hash)
    {
    case "#/calendar":
        content.load("calendar.php");
        break;
    case "#/media":
        content.load("media.php");
        break;
    case "#/social":
        content.load("social.php");
        break;
    case "#/settings":
        content.load("settings.php");
        break;
    default:
        content.load("home.php");
        title.text("Debafla");
    }
});
```

Now I'm building a video galery, so i wanted to use URLs like these:

```
example.com/#/video/12485
```

So video.php need to be loaded in the content div en i need to get the video with ID 12485 from the DB. But how can I cover these hash pages in javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the split method:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    switch(location.hash.split("/")[1])
    {
    case "calendar":
        content.load("calendar.php");
        break;
    case "media":
        content.load("media.php");
        break;
    case "social":
        content.load("social.php");
        break;
    case "settings":
        content.load("settings.php");
        break;
    case "video":
        content.load("video.php?v=" + location.hash.split("/")[2]);
        break;
    default:
        content.load("home.php");
        title.text("Debafla");
    }
});
```

Comment: so simple but so effective, also seems the best solution for the future

Comment: Yup, it should work for future requirements as long as the `#/keyword/data` format is kept. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra if-else condition, using the following pattern:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    if (/^#\/video\/\d+$/.test(location.hash)) { //hash equals #/video/numbers ?
        var num = location.hash.match(/\d+/)[0]; //12485, for example
         //do something, for example:
        content.load("video.php?video_id=" + num);

    } else {//Else switch:
        switch(location.hash)
       {
     ...
```